# Get maximum Rectangle placed within Polygon or Path

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

How to get maximum Rectangle that can be placed within Path or Polygon.
I need some functionality to get it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610462/finding-an-axis-aligned-rectangle-inside-a-polygon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site has a possible algorithm: http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2003/DanielSud/

The same site also has a java applet with source code, but the applet uses a brute-force solution, not the algorithm described on the page.