# an algorithm for fitting a rectangle inside a polygon

Tags: algorithm, polygon, computational-geometry, rectangles

I have a kind of cutting problem. There is an irregular polygon that doesn't have any holes and a list of standard sized of rectangular tiles and their values.

I want an efficient algorithm to find the single best valued tile that fit in this polygon; or an algorithm that just says if a single tile can fit inside the polygon. And it should run in deterministic time for irregular polygons with less than 100 vertices.

Please consider that you can rotate the polygon and tiles.
Answers/hints for both convex and non-convex polygons are appreciated.

Comment: A Google search on [rectangle inside polygon] returns some interesting results, including this research paper: http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~jeschmid/public/Knauer2012.pdf, and a few SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/610462/56778, and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10214829/56778

Comment: You mentioned your polygons are irregular.  Are they convex?

Comment: Of course I had Googled it before. But thanks for your guidance. And I edited the problem.

Comment: Here's a simple approximation idea that I would try for a convex polygon.  First rotate it until it's as horizontal as possible (look for a diameter and make it horizontal).  Given a tile, rotate that too, if necessary, to make it horizontal.  Then place it in the center of the polygon's bounding rectangle, and see which vertices are inside the polygon.  If only one or two adjacent vertices are outside, move the tile in the obvious direction and see if you can get them all inside.

Comment: Can you describe why @JimMischel's links don't suffice?

Comment: Because I don't want to find "an axis-aligned rectangle" or  "the largest one" inside a polygon. All I want is finding the answer this question : "**Can this specific rectangle fit inside this polygon or not?**" and I mention that the rectangle **can rotate**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many hopeless searches, I think there isn't any specific algorithm for this problem. Until, I found [this old paper about polygon containment problem.](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/PolygContainmentProb.pdf)
That mentioned article, present a really good algorithm to consider if a polygon with **n** points can fit a polygon with **m** points or not.
 The algorithm is of O(n^3 m^3(n+m)log(n+m)) in general for two transportable and rotatable 2D polygon.

I hope it can help you, if you are searching for such an irregular algorithm in computational geometry.

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: I've never read any literature on this, so there might be a better way of doing this.  This solution is just what I've thought about after having read your question.

A rectangle has two important measurements - it's height and it's width

now if we start with a polygon and a rectangle:

[image: polygon and rectangle]

1: go around the perimeter of the polygon and take note of all the places the **height** of the rectangle will fit in the polygon (you can store this as a polygon*):

[image: where will the hight fit?]

2: go around the perimeter of the **new polygon you just made** and take note of all the places the **width** of the rectangle will fit in the polygon (again, you can store this as a polygon):

[image: where will the width fit?]

3: the rectangle should fit within this new polygon (just be careful that you position the rectangle inside the polygon correctly, as this is a polygon - not a rectangle.  If you align the top left node of the rectangle with the top left node of this new polygon, you should be ok)

4: if no area can be found that the rectangle will fit in, rotate the polygon by a couple of degrees, and try again.

*Note: in some polygons, you will get more than one place a rectangle can be fitted:

[image: more than one rectangle can be fitted here]

Comment: Thanks for your answer; but it isn't what I want.
I want an algorithm to solve **the Polygon containment by Rectangle(s) Problem**.

Comment: @aisa My algorithm will tell you how many different places a rectangle will fit inside a polygon at each given rotation.  So if the number of places is zero, the rectangle will not fit in at that rotation.  If the number of places is > zero, the rectangle will fit in at that rotation.  So with a simple conditional statement, you can check for what you need.  Unless you actually want to solve this problem because you have immensely tight tolerances, you should be able to tune the number of degrees you turn for each iteration of my algorithm to your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

This might help. It comes with the source code written Java

http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2003/DanielSud/

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I mentioned that the polygon can rotate. and it's not necessarily a Convex one. Anyway, again thanks for your link.