# Largest Area Axis-Aligned Rectangle Inside Convex Polygon

Tags: c++, opencv, geometry, computational-geometry

I am looking to find code or a data flow diagram that will describe the process for finding the largest-area axis aligned rectangle inside a convex polygon.

I have looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610462/finding-an-axis-aligned-rectangle-inside-a-polygon), and followed the suggested [link](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2003/DanielSud/) to no avail.

To date, I have completed code for "2 corners on the boundary of P". I am stuck trying to complete the code for "3 corners on the boundary of P". My issue mainly lies inside the "Tentative Prune-and-Search" method described [here](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/cgi-bin/tr/1993/TR-93-30.pdf).

Comment: what do you mean by "largest"? largest area?

Comment: Yes i mean largest area. sorry i wasn't clear.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/32682512/5008845

Comment: Proposed "duplicate" answers quite different question.